# ASP.NET 3.5 Customize DataPager

Tags: asp.net, css, datapager

I currently have paging done manually and I use this code to display it

```
<div class="pages_numbers">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">&raquo; </a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I want to use the DataPager control to do the paging for me, I've gotten the paging to work great, but I cant get the CSS Styles to stick and display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to the datapager for seo

```
QueryStringField="id"
```

Then added CSS Classes to the elements and changed my CSS

```
<Fields>
<asp:NextPreviousPagerField FirstPageText="&lt;&lt;" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" ButtonCssClass="PageItem" />
<asp:NumericPagerField CurrentPageLabelCssClass="PageItem" NumericButtonCssClass="PageItem"  NextPreviousButtonCssClass="PageItem" />
<asp:NextPreviousPagerField LastPageText="&gt;&gt;" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" ButtonCssClass="PageItem" />
</Fields>
```